# Sorting ListBox with MVVM code binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a ListBox which happily displays data using a code-behind MVVM object. However, I want to sort the entries and so I thought an intermediate CollectionViewSource might work. But instead the program crashes on startup.

Original xaml extract:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
    DisplayMemberPath="name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
    Name="CategoriesListBox" />
```

Code behind extract:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private trainCategory[] _categories;
        private trainCategory _selectedCategory;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public trainCategory[] Categories
        {
            get { return _categories; }
            set
            {
                if (_categories == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _categories = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Categories");
            }
        } //etc
```

Replacement XAML for ListBox:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
    DisplayMemberPath="name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}"
    Name="CategoriesListBox" />
```

And the CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding Categories}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="name"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

It seems to me that the CollectionViewSource goes in between the view model and the ListBox, but it clearly doesn't (or I've done it wrong). Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: What sort of exception do you get when it crashes?

Comment: You can use the CollectionView class instead. For your property it should be like: `public CollectionView Categories`. And you can bind this propeprty directly to the listbox as if it was a collection.

Comment: Of course, I can't recreate the exception now, and to add insult to injury, it's sorted (as in A-Z and metaphorically speaking)! I shall have to investigate CollectionView further though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your original xaml

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="name" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
    Name="CategoriesListBox" />
```

Update your View Model to use a List instead:

```
   public List<trainCategory> _categories;
   public List<trainCategory> Categories 
    { 
        get 
        {   // This LINQ statement returns a sorted list
            return (from c in _categories
                    orderby c
                    select c);
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (_categories == value) 
            { 
                return; 
            } 
            _categories = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("Categories"); 
        } 
    } //etc
```

Then you can skip all that nastiness of trying to bind to a static resporce. Just bind strait to the property in your view model.

Alternately, you can still use arrays as your backing variable in your viewmodel:

```
   public trainCategory[] _categories;
   public List<trainCategory> Categories 
    { 
        get 
        {   // This LINQ statement returns a sorted list
            return (from c in _categories
                    orderby c
                    select c).ToList();
        } 
        set 
        { 
            if (_categories == value.ToArray()) 
            { 
                return; 
            } 
            _categories = value.ToArray();
            RaisePropertyChanged("Categories");
        } 
    } //etc
```

Comment: Elegant, though the data source is fixed as an array at the moment. I think I could probably do a bit of copying to/from Lists instead, though it's a little more work to try it.

Comment: An Array can be cast to a list rather quickly, actually. Another LINQ statement to the rescue: List<Items> = MyItemsArray.ToList(); Also, there is no reason, really, why you couldn't just change the List<trainCategory> to an array, like you did you your sample. In fact... more code imcomming.

Comment: Yes, I have to cast to a list and back again just to add or delete an item! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What exception are you getting on startup? Remember to have your `Resources` section before all other code that needs to use the resources.

An alternative to that would be:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" DisplayMemberPath="name" Name="CategoriesListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>
                <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Categories}">
                    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="name"/>
                    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                </CollectionViewSource>
            </Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

Also remember to have the proper `xmlns` declaration for `scm` in any case.

Comment: "Property 'ItemsSource' does not support values of type 'CollectionViewSource'". I should have mentioned this is VS2008 and .net3.5, if that makes any difference. I've got scm as xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to make that work either - it compiles and runs, but the listbox is now empty. But as an exercise for myself I will try to find out why. Thanks.